# Proving the decomposibility of entropy

Tags: solution-verification, information-theory

Which would be the following:
$$H\left (p\right ) = \sum_{i=1}^{I} p_{i} \log \frac{1}{p_{i}}=H\left (p_{1}, 1-p_{1}\right )+\left (1-p_{1}\right ) H\left (\frac{p_{2}}{1-p_{1}}, \frac{p_{3}}{1-p_{1}}, \ldots, \frac{p_{I}}{1-p_{1}}\right )$$

With $H$ as the entropy and $p$ as a probability vector.

- The definition of entropy as used here: $\mathrm {H} (X)=-\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\mathrm {P} (x_{i})\log \mathrm {P} (x_{i})}$.

---

Now I do have a correct proof, but would rather see if my own proof is correct or not, and where the problem is in the latter case.

First, we lay down a few equations which we will be using to complete our proof:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\left (1-p_{1}\right ) H\left (\frac{p_{2}}{1-p_{1}}, \ldots, \frac{p_{I}}{1-p_{1}}\right ) \\&= \left (1-p_{1}\right ) \left (H\left (\frac{p_{2}}{1-p_{1}}\right ) + \ldots + H\left (\frac{p_{I}}{1-p_{1}}\right )\right )\\
&= \left (1-p_{1}\right ) \left (\left (\frac{1}{1-p_1}\right ) \left (H\left (P_2\right )+\ldots+H\left (P_I\right )\right ) + H\left (\frac{1}{1-p_1}\right ) \left (p_2+\ldots+p_I\right )\right ) 
\end{aligned}$$

We know that $\left (p_2+\ldots p_i\right ) = \left (1-p_1\right )$, so continuing the above:

$$\begin{aligned}
&= H\left (P_2\right )+\ldots+H\left (P_I\right ) + \left (1-p_{1}\right )\log{\left (1-p_1\right )}
\end{aligned}$$

We also have:
$$\begin{aligned}
H\left (1-p_1\right ) + \left (1-p_{1}\right )\log{\left (1-p_1\right )} &= \left (1-p_1\right )\left (\log\frac{1}{1-p_1}+\log\left (1-p_1\right )\right ) \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}$$

Putting the above together:

$$\begin{aligned}
H\left (p_{1}, 1-p_{1}\right )+\left (1-p_{1}\right ) H\left (\frac{p_{2}}{1-p_{1}}, \frac{p_{3}}{1-p_{1}}, \ldots, \frac{p_{i}}{1-p_{1}}\right ) &= H\left (p_1\right )+\ldots+H\left (p_i\right ) \\
&= H\left (p\right )
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I cannot make sense of this. Why, in your first equation, you "distribute" the $H$? Further, what do you mean by $H(p_2)$ ? The entropy, when writen as a function, should take as argument a probability distribution. I don't know what you mean when you write eg $H( 1/(1-p_i))$

Comment: It seems OK. You use H as something more general than an entropy (where the sum of probability should be 1) but once we know that, it is OK. The last part of yout third equation should be $\frac{p_2+ \cdots + p_I}{1-P_1}$ instead of $p_2+ \cdots + p_I$ if you keep it within the parenthesis.

Comment: @leonbloy By $H(p_2)$ I basically mean $p_2\log1/p_2$, but to be honest I am not sure if this is a correct usage of the notation (I have used it because the textbook seems to be using a similar notation for the joint entropy). About the distribution I did so to be able to end up with $H(p)$ to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is basically right, but should not use $H()$ for two different things, I'd define instead $g(x)= x log(1/x)$ and so on.

An alternative (more general and perhaps more elegant) proof: consider two random variables $X_1$ $X_2$, taking values on $1,2 \cdots m$, and $m+1, m+2 \cdots n$ with given pmf $p_1(i)$ and $p_2(j)$. We form a third rv $Y=X_1$ with prob $a$, $Y=X_2$ otherwise. This is know as an (non overlapping) [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).

Then $$H(Z)=h(a) + \alpha H(X_1) +(1-a) H(X_2)$$

where $h(\alpha)= -a \log a - (1-a) \log (1-a)$.

Proof: define the indicator variable $E=1$ if $Y=X_1$, elsewhere $E=2$.

Notice that $H(E|Z)=0$ (knowing $Z$ we know if it came from $X_1$ or $X_2$)

Then $$H(E,Z)=H(Z)+H(E|Z) = H(E)+H(Z|E) \implies H(Z)=H(E)+H(Z|E)$$
But $H(E)=h(a)$ (Bernoulli variable), and
$$H(Z|E) = P(E=1) H(Z|E=1) +P(E=2) H(Z|E=2)= a H(X_1) +(1-a) H(X_2)$$

Your equation is a special case, with $m=1$ and $a=p_1$.