# Binary entropy and mixing property to simplify a function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Let  $ f(\vec{p},\vec{q})=h(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_iq_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_ih(q_i)$ where $\vec{p}=[p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_n]$ and $\vec{q}=[q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n].$

Here, $h(.)$ indicates the [binary entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function). Also $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i=1$. ($q_i's$ doesn't sum to 1 but  $q_i's\lt$ 1).

I am looking for alternate representations or simplified forms of $ f(\vec{p},\vec{q})$.

**One of my thoughts is to extend [this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277043/proving-an-identity-involving-binary-entropy) which makes use of the mixing property of entropy. Is this extension possible?**

Also, are there any other characterization of $ f(\vec{p},\vec{q})$?

**Why I am interested in this**:
In my case, $q_i's$ are exponential functions (say for example, $q_i= e^{-\frac{a}{i+b}}$) whereas $p_i's$ are coming from a binomial PMF. Hencein $ f(\vec{p},\vec{q})$, the $h(q_i)'s$ are hard to compute and therefore I am interested in alternate forms of $ f(\vec{p},\vec{q})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps:

Let $X_i$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $q_i = P(X_i =1)$.

Let $W$ be a random variable (independent of $X_i$) taking values on $i=1,2 \cdots n$ with $P(W=i)=p_i$.

Let's define a new Bernoulli variable $Y$, which corresponds to picking one of $X_i$ with prob $p_i$, i.e. $Y= X_W$

Then $$\begin{align}
A &= h(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_iq_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i h(q_i) \\
&= H(Y) - H(Y|W) \\
&= I(Y;W) \\
&= H(W) - H(W|Y) \\
&= H(\{p_i\}) - b \, H\left(\frac{\{p_i q_i\}}{b}\right) -(1-b)H\left(\frac{\{p_i (1-q_i)\}}{1-b}\right)
\end{align}
$$

where $b= \sum p_i qi$

Added: In [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279387/entropy-of-a-perturbed-or-weighted-binomial-random-variable/4280462#4280462) I develop an approximation for nearly constant $q_i$.

Comment: this might be helpful. I am trying to see if that's the case. Thanks for the answer. Now, I am thinking of how can I approximate the second and third terms in the simplification you provided. I will try to work on it and ask a different question if it seems unclear to me.