# Entropy of a perturbed or weighted binomial random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Let $W$ be a Binomial random variable  taking values on $i=1,2 \cdots n$ with $P(W=i)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
i
\end{array}\right) p^{i} (1-p)^{n-i}=p_i$.

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), the entropy of $W$ is given by $H(W)=H(\{p_i\})=\frac{1}{2} \log _{2}(2 \pi e n p (1-p))+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$

Now, consider $q_i=e^{-{(\frac{a}{bi+c}})}$,where $a,b,c$ are constants $\geq 0$.

How can I compute ( **atleast approximately**) the entropy  $H\left(\frac{\left\{p_{i} q_{i}\right\}}{d}\right),$ where $d=\sum p_iq_i$ is the normalizing factor?

The context of this question comes from [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277574/binary-entropy-and-mixing-property-to-simplify-a-function). My aim is to compute
$G=d H\left(\frac{\left\{p_{i} q_{i}\right\}}{d}\right)+(1-d) H\left(\frac{\left\{p_{i}\left(1-q_{i}\right)\right\}}{1-d}\right)$ eventually.

**Subquestion**: I am also interested in knowing if $G$ is increasing with $c$ whereas decreasing with $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the entropy difference:$$
D = H(\{p_i\}) -G = H(\{p_i\}) - r H\left(\frac{\left\{p_{i} q_{i}\right\}}{r}\right)-(1-r) H\left(\frac{\left\{p_{i}\left(1-q_{i}\right)\right\}}{1-r}\right) \tag 1$$

(I use $r=\sum q_i p_i$ instead of $d$ because of  readability)

Using natural logarithms (entropy in nats), letting $\delta_i = p'_i-p_i=\frac{q_i p_i}{r}-p_i$, doing a second order Taylor expansion around $\delta_i=0$ (the first order term vanishes) I get:

$$D \approx \frac{1}{ 2r(1-r)} \sum_i p_i (r - q_i)^2=\frac{\sum_i p_i q_i^2 - r^2 }{ 2r(1-r)} \tag 2$$

This approximation should be good for small $\delta_i$, that is, for $q_i$ nearly constant.

For example: for $p = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.15)$ and $q=(0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38)$ I get $D= 0.0012702$ while the approximation gives $0.0012669$.

The approximation can be also be written as

$$D \approx \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \mu (1-\mu)}
$$
where $\mu, \sigma^2$ are the mean and variance of a random variable taking values $q_i$ with probabilities $p_i$. Also, this can be
obtained by doing a Taylor expansion of the binary entropy function, around $\mu$, in the first equation [in the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4277745/312).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I have some confusion in getting the Taylor series expansion. Specifically, In $D(x)=f(a)+f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)^{1}+\frac{1}{2} f^{\prime \prime}(a)(x-a)^{2}$,  what are you considering as $x$. I would appreciate if you could add an intermediate step before eqn(2).

Comment: As I said above, $x$ is $\delta_i$ . The intermediate steps are too many to write down. It's quite simpler to define the rv $X$ (taking values $q_i$ with probabilities $p_i$) and compute, notice that $\sum p_i q_i = E(X)$ etc, and apply the Taylor expansion for $E[h(X)]$ , as I do here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536459/expected-value-of-square-root-of-poisson-random-variable/1537267#1537267

Comment: Another clarification: I see that you mention the approximation is good for small $\delta_i$ vals or in other words approximately constant $q_i's$. For other general cases, Is it possible to say that the approximation to $D$ you established will be a lower bound or upper bound?

Comment: I doubt that it can be useful as a bound.

Comment: Is the approximation $D$ in bits or nats?

Comment: As I said: nats